# Button over image in pyQt, Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

i have created a widget(Qlabel) which displays the image using pixmap. now, i want to add few buttons over that image(basically, over widget containing pixmap, ie. Qlabel)

Kindly refer to the attached image.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Does the image have to be on top of Qlabel?

I would set the required image as the background to a container type widget. Probably a frame and then put the buttons onto the frame.

Also Have a look a Qt Creator, I did some GUI work with pyqt in the past, and this really helped me to build the gui quickly and keep it separate from the code.

Comment: No, it need not be on Qlabel.
Which widget should i use , Qframe?

Also, i need to create this button on runtime according to the number set.

thanks for the replyh